# Is it possible to create a Faraday cage transparent to only violet/blue light from natural white light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

If a Faraday cage’s hole size determines the wavelength of light which can penetrate it then I would imagine this would be possible.

Comment: Nothing easier than this: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_filter#Bandpass. To let through separate wavelengths, say IR and UV, one need two filters and holding them one behind the other cancel out both wavelengths. But to have a broad filter = Bandpass and to let throught some wavelengths from .. to .. is possiblean din optics well done.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler But I could interpret this as  only asking for a long-wave cutoff filter, so a screen -type filter in this case  is theoretically possible. (tho' with a lousy cut-off slope

Answer (score 3):

The blue end of the spectrum is higher frequency, meaning shorter wavelength.  A cage that can block blue is going to block (technically attenuate) the given wavelength and any that are longer (lower frequency).  If you start blocking at blue, you'll be blocking the entire visible spectrum and on down into the IR, microwave, and radio.

To filter out UV, the mesh would have to be so fine that it easily blocks everything below it, including the entire visible spectrum.

Comment: Just to make this post more complete: there are methods (not Faraday cage) for filtering high frequency radiation while allowing lower frequencies to pass through, most rely on material science concepts. Sunscreen is an example of a substance which blocks high frequency light (UV) and allows visible light to pass.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I meant to allow only blue and violet to pass through. Sorry for the confusion. If two polarizing films 90 degrees to each other (effectively a Faraday cage) will not permit visible light through am I correct to believe that increasing the spaces slightly between each polarizing strip in the film would allow only these shorter wavelength colors through?

Comment: If you want to only allow blue/UV through you still cannot do that with "only" a Faraday Cage.  You can us one which blocks everything longer than blue, but you'll need another method as James Rowland suggests to block the shorter frequencies in constructing your "band pass" filter.

Comment: for completeness, there are glass filters e.g. UG11 that transmit in the UV and not visible, as well as interference filters that can be made to transmit at almost any small range of wavelengths you  choose as well as numerous compounds, such a CuSO$_4$ that transmit ir and uv but not much visible light etc.